# Writing an existing list to a new list in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm trying to write a list inputted by the user to a new list in Prolog. I have figured out how to do it using a reverse method and it works fine. My problem is that I need it to stop at the element the user inputs along with the list (so I can repeat this value again before adding the remainder of the list). For example if I was to input

```
repeat_nth(3, [a,b,c,d,e], X).
```

its output should be

```
X = [a,b,c,c,d,e].
```

When I try to introduce a variable 'N' to count until the element to be repeated prolog just tells me 'no'. Here is my code:

```
new_list(N,[H|T],A,L2):- N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    new_list(N1,T,[H|A],L2). 
new_list(0,[],A,A).
repeat_nth(N,L1,L2):- new_list(N,L1,[],L2).
```

Comment: Your first clause counts down and copies elements to the new accumulator list (in reverse order). That is basically OK, but keep in mind that when you're done you'll have to reverse the list. But your base case assumes that when `N` counts down to zero, you're at the exact end of your input list. In other words, `new_list` will only succeed if the length of the input list is exactly `N`. In addition, the `new_list` predicate doesn't anywhere actually duplicate the Nth element. The base case is where you'd want to do that in this particular implementation.

Comment: Just as hint: for this particular problem, you don't need an accumulator, and you can avoid doing a "reverse". You want a predicate `repeat_nth(N, [H|T], [H|T1])` for the case where `N > 1`, and another, `repeat_nth(1, [H|T], [H,H|T]).`

Comment: Thanks, I used the reverse so that I could see results and then implement the counter etc so I could build it in stages as I'm finding recursion really difficult to understand.. Unfortunately I still really don't get it.. by using your suggestion i still get the "singleton variable" error.. I just don't know why! I have read countless websites about recursion and lists and my brain is mush right now I just really don't get it! :(

Comment: Show how you used the hints I gave. The first clause (`repeat_nth(N, [H|T], [H|T1])` for `N > 1`) needs to have a little code written for it. The second stands on its own.

Comment: @mbratch I've tried many different variations.. first I declared the escape predicate (The empty one):'repeat_nth(0, [], []).' Then I tried to begin with the hint decreasing N and feeding it back in so that it would recurse:'repeat_nth(N, [H|T], [H|T1]):-
        N > 1,
        N1 is N - 1,
        repeat_nth(N1, [H|T], [H|T1]).' In a recursive statment I have written before for division the counter decremented after the recall statement so I tried it that way too and It didn't work.. Is the hint line you gave me actually concatenating the lists or does the extra code need to do this?

Comment: I also tried to start the statement with my variables L1 and L2 but then thats where I got the singleton variables error because they were declared and not used again? So I assume that the head and tails need to be declared at the beginning and then different data needs to be fed back in? When I follow my division one I get it completely as I went through it 100's of times step by step with pen and paper.. but now lists are involved I'm so stuck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate can be built up from a couple of cases. If you think about them logically first and express them in a sentence or two, it can help determine the clauses.

**Base case:** the list, `[H|T]` with the first element (`H`, element number 1) repeated is a list where the head (`H`) appears twice. The tail (`T`) remains the same:

```
repeat_nth(1, [H|T], [H,H|T]).
```

**Recursive case:** for N > 1, to repeat the Nth term of a list `[H|T]`, I copy over the head (`H`) and then repeat the (N-1)st term (`N1 is N-1`) of the tail (`T`) of the first list, and that is the tail of the second (`T1`):

```
repeat_nth(N, [H|T], [H|T1]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N-1,
    repeat_nth(N1, T, T1).
```

The above two clauses are all that's needed. One of your attempts described in your comments was very close! The error was in that last line of the second clause. You tried:

```
repeat_nth(N1, [H|T], [H|T1]).
```

So you carried along the `H` which was incorrect. `H` is already taken care of in the head of the clause, and the purpose of this new call is to take care of the tails (as the description of the recursive case indicates).

Comment: Ohhhh! I knew I needed to ditch the head.. I didn't think of the simplest way.. Not sending it back to the first clause! Thankyou ever so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
...
Call: (10) new_list(0, [d, e], [c, b, a], _G2728)
Call: (11) 0>0
Fail: (11) 0>0
...
```

Seems your code is missing the base case. It's fairly clear that `[d,e]` cannot match `[]`.